# Rearranging ruby hash with a condition

Tags: ruby, hash

EDITED:
 How do we take the following forward

```
fields = [{"Name"=>"CONTACT.MAILADDRESS.LATITUDE", "dataName"=>"Pt_FieldDouble", "externalDataName"=>"number", "isRequired"=>"false", "isReadOnly"=>"false", "maxLength"=>"10", "DisplayLabel"=>"Latitude", "Description"=>"Latitude", "id"=>"999505900000211"},
 {"Name"=>"CONTACT.MAILADDRESS.LONGITUDE", "dataName"=>"Pt_FieldDouble", "externalDataName"=>"number", "isRequired"=>"false", "isReadOnly"=>"false", "maxLength"=>"11", "DisplayLabel"=>"Longitude", "Description"=>"Longitude", "id"=>"999505900000212"},
 {"Name"=>"CONTACT.STATE", "dataName"=>"Pt_FieldString", "externalDataName"=>"string", "isRequired"=>"false", "isReadOnly"=>"false", "maxLength"=>"0", "DisplayLabel"=>"Status", "Description"=>"Active/Inactive", "id"=>"999505900000166"},
 {"Name"=>"XXSTATUS", "dataName"=>"Pt_FieldString", "externalDataName"=>"string", "isRequired"=>"false", "isReadOnly"=>"false", "maxLength"=>"0", "DisplayLabel"=>"XStatus", "Description"=>"Active/Inactive", "id"=>"99950591200166"}] 

output = 
     [{"CONTACT" =>
        { "MAILADDRESS" =>
           { "Name" => "LATITUDE", "dataName"=>"Pt_FieldDouble", "externalDataName"=>"number", "isRequired"=>"false", "isReadOnly"=>"false", "maxLength"=>"10", "DisplayLabel"=>"Latitude", "Description"=>"Latitude", "id"=>"999505900000211"},
           { "Name" => "LATITUDE", "dataName"=>"Pt_FieldDouble", "externalDataName"=>"number", "isRequired"=>"false", "isReadOnly"=>"false", "maxLength"=>"11", "DisplayLabel"=>"Longitude", "Description"=>"Longitude", "id"=>"999505900000212"}},
        { "Name" =>"STATE", "dataName"=>"Pt_FieldString", "externalDataName"=>"string", "isRequired"=>"false", "isReadOnly"=>"false", "maxLength"=>"0", "DisplayLabel"=>"Status", "Description"=>"Active/Inactive", "id"=>"999505900000166"}},
      { "Name" =>"XXSTATUS", "dataName"=>"Pt_FieldString", "externalDataName"=>"string", "isRequired"=>"false", "isReadOnly"=>"false", "maxLength"=>"0", "DisplayLabel"=>"XStatus", "Description"=>"Active/Inactive", "id"=>"99950591200166"}]
```

I tried

fields.map { |i| {i["Name"] => i.except("Name")}}

```
[{"CONTACT.MAILADDRESS.LATITUDE"=>{"dataName"=>"Pt_FieldDouble", "externalDataName"=>"number", "isRequired"=>"false", "isReadOnly"=>"false", "maxLength"=>"10", "DisplayLabel"=>"Latitude", "Description"=>"Latitude", "id"=>"999505900000211"}},
{"CONTACT.MAILADDRESS.LONGITUDE"=>{"dataName"=>"Pt_FieldDouble", "externalDataName"=>"number", "isRequired"=>"false", "isReadOnly"=>"false", "maxLength"=>"11", "DisplayLabel"=>"Longitude", "Description"=>"Longitude", "id"=>"999505900000212"}},
{"CONTACT.STATUS"=>{"dataName"=>"Pt_FieldString", "externalDataName"=>"string", "isRequired"=>"false", "isReadOnly"=>"false", "maxLength"=>"0", "DisplayLabel"=>"Status", "Description"=>"Active/Inactive", "id"=>"999505900000166"}}]
```

Struck how to split the keys and put the values together

Comment: There's no need to accept an answer right away. There might be better answers if you wait a bit.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is similar to a [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), so you could parse the name parts and create a nested hash with [`each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) and [`inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject). This should work with any nested depth :

```
fields = [{"Name"=>"CONTACT.MAILADDRESS.LATITUDE", "dataName"=>"Pt_FieldDouble", "externalDataName"=>"number", "isRequired"=>"false", "isReadOnly"=>"false", "maxLength"=>"10", "DisplayLabel"=>"Latitude", "Description"=>"Latitude", "id"=>"999505900000211"},
 {"Name"=>"CONTACT.MAILADDRESS.LONGITUDE", "dataName"=>"Pt_FieldDouble", "externalDataName"=>"number", "isRequired"=>"false", "isReadOnly"=>"false", "maxLength"=>"11", "DisplayLabel"=>"Longitude", "Description"=>"Longitude", "id"=>"999505900000212"},
 {"Name"=>"CONTACT.STATUS", "dataName"=>"Pt_FieldString", "externalDataName"=>"string", "isRequired"=>"false", "isReadOnly"=>"false", "maxLength"=>"0", "DisplayLabel"=>"Status", "Description"=>"Active/Inactive", "id"=>"999505900000166"}]

tree = fields.each_with_object({}) do |field, tree|
  field = field.dup
  names = field.delete("Name").split('.')
  node = names.inject(tree) do |node, name|
    node[name] ||= {}
  end
  node.merge!(field)
end

require 'pp'
pp tree
# {"CONTACT"=>
#   {"MAILADDRESS"=>
#     {"LATITUDE"=>
#       {"dataName"=>"Pt_FieldDouble",
#        "externalDataName"=>"number",
#        "isRequired"=>"false",
#        "isReadOnly"=>"false",
#        "maxLength"=>"10",
#        "DisplayLabel"=>"Latitude",
#        "Description"=>"Latitude",
#        "id"=>"999505900000211"},
#      "LONGITUDE"=>
#       {"dataName"=>"Pt_FieldDouble",
#        "externalDataName"=>"number",
#        "isRequired"=>"false",
#        "isReadOnly"=>"false",
#        "maxLength"=>"11",
#        "DisplayLabel"=>"Longitude",
#        "Description"=>"Longitude",
#        "id"=>"999505900000212"}},
#    "STATUS"=>
#     {"dataName"=>"Pt_FieldString",
#      "externalDataName"=>"string",
#      "isRequired"=>"false",
#      "isReadOnly"=>"false",
#      "maxLength"=>"0",
#      "DisplayLabel"=>"Status",
#      "Description"=>"Active/Inactive",
#      "id"=>"999505900000166"}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Kind of wordy, but you can do...

```
 output = {}

 pointer = nil

 fields.each do |field|
  pointer = output
  sections = field['Name'].split('.').each do |section|
    pointer[section] ||= {}
    pointer = pointer[section]
  end
  pointer.merge!(field)
  pointer.delete('Name')
end 
output
```

Comment: Thanks! There is a little issue with this. In this case it returns, `"STATUS"=>{nil=>{"dataName"=>"Pt_FieldString", ....`

Comment: Thanks. This works. Please look at the edited request